# Почему кофе крепкий?

Tags: фразеология

Здравствуйте!
На сообществе ВКонтакте задали вопрос: "Почему кофе крепкий?" Крепким может быть засов, орех, что-то еще. Крепкий - значит, прочный. Кофе же, по идее, должен быть насыщенным, густым. Но он крепкий.
Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово "крепкий" - общеславянское с индоевропейским корнем, его старшее значение - "сильный, прочный", сравнить: craft (англ.), Kraft (нем.) - сила. Также у греков "kripis"  - фундамент, основание.

Однако, как и  в большинстве случаев, с течением времени происходит развитие старшего значения слова, теперь крепкий - это ещё и "твердый, здоровый, надежный".

И наконец, можно отметить появление еще одного интересного значения: словом "крепкий" называют  признаки самые различные, но при этом имеющие  значительную степень проявления, то есть "сильные" признаки: крепкий (насыщенный) кофе, крепкие (стойкие) духи, крепкий (глубокий) сон.

Answer (score 4):

Крепкими могут быть и алкоголь, и сон, и здоровье, и вера. Крепкий кофе — это насыщенный, густой, очень "плотный", так сказать. Чем больше плотность вещества, тем оно, как правило, крепче. Вот и вся аналогия.

Answer (score 0):

а у англичан неразбавленный виски  - Dare strait, а не kraft

Comment: Аналогия понятна, но боюсь, не всем. Пишите более полный ответ.